# Best way to modify memory in VxWorks

Tags: memory, embedded, vxworks

I'm writing a test script in python that will manipulate memory in the system.

I know the m command (modify memory) exists; however, it seems extremely clunky. Our test suite does not handle input prompts very gracefully either. I believe there must be something better out there.

In your experience, what other ways are there to modify memory in VxWorks?

Comment: Write a quick C function that does what you want, and invoke it from python...

Comment: Is the Python script running on the target or the host?

Comment: It is running on the host.

Comment: There used to be [tcl stuff](http://csg.lbl.gov/pipermail/vxwexplo/2003-July/002442.html) that used the *gopher* protocol.  I have no idea if this fits with Python or if it applies to newer vxWorks.  You use to send that *gopher* stuff to a socket.  The table was somewhere in WRS's manuals.

Answer (score 1):

Target shell commands in VxWorks are no more that C functions - the shell includes a symbol table generated at build time that includes all functions with external linkage.  As such the "m" command is in fact a simple a C function ([see here](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrLib.html#m)).  You could equally call memset() or memcpy() or write your own function.

To execute function calls on the target from a host, without using the target or host shell, you might consider using [RPC](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/rpcLib.html#top) using [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org) on the host perhaps.